# Possibility of looker creating tables on SF/BQ using lookml? DBT as reference

Tags: looker

Is there any possible way of creating tables on snowflake/biqguery using LookMl

I didnt find any possible way of creating.i tried creating tables in snowflake and refered those tables as views in Looker.
Do we need to use dbt tool for that?